# SQLite :memory: database usage with using / dispose

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have wrapped all of my `SQL Connections` in a `using` statement.

```
using (DbConnection dbConnection = GetConnection())
{
    using (DbCommand dbCommand = dbConnection.CreateCommand(cmdInsert))
    {
        //some work
    }
}
```

For `UnitTests` I supposed to use a `:memory: database`, but the `database` is automatically deleted, after closing the connection.

https://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html

> The database is automatically deleted and memory is reclaimed when the last connection to the database closes.

Is there a solution how to use a `:memory: database` and use `using`? I don't want to write exactly the same code twice without `using`..

## Complete Example

### Database

```
public abstract class SqliteBase
{
    public string ConnectionString;

    protected SqliteBase()
    {      
        SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder
        {
            DataSource = ":memory:",
            ForeignKeys = true,
            DefaultTimeout = 3,
            DateTimeKind = DateTimeKind.Utc,
            Pooling = false             
        };

        ConnectionString = builder.ConnectionString + ";mode=memory;cache=shared";
    }

    private DbConnection _MemoryConnection;
    protected DbConnection GetConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            if (_MemoryConnection == null)
            {
                _MemoryConnection = new SQLiteConnection(ConnectionString);                    
                _MemoryConnection.Open();
            }

            DbConnection dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection(ConnectionString);
            dbConnection.Open();

            return dbConnection;
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error opening database connection.", ex);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a table in the SQL database if it does not exist
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="tableName">The name of the table</param>
    /// <param name="columns">Comma separated column names</param>
    protected void CreateTable(string tableName, string columns)
    {
        using (DbConnection dbConnection = GetConnection())
        {
            using (DbCommand dbCommand = dbConnection.CreateCommand($"create table if not exists {tableName} ({columns})"))
            {
                dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
}

public class FooDatabase : SqliteBase
{
    public FooDatabase()
    {
        CreateTable("FooTable", "Foo TEXT");
    }

    public void DoFoo()
    {
        using (DbConnection dbConnection = GetConnection())
        {
            using (DbCommand dbCommand = dbConnection.CreateCommand("Select * from FooTable"))
            {
                dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Unit Test

```
public static class SQLiteTestSetup
{
    public static FooDatabase ClassInit()
    {
       return new FooDatabase();
    }

    public static void Cleanup()
    {

    }
}

public abstract class SQLiteTestBase
{
    public static FooDatabase Database { get; set; }

    [TestMethod]
    public void DoSomeFooTest()
    {
        Database.DoFoo();
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class SQLiteTest : SQLiteTestBase
{
    [ClassInitialize]
    public static void ClassInit(TestContext context)
    {
        Database = SQLiteTestSetup.ClassInit();
    }

    [ClassCleanup]
    public static void ClassCleanup() => SQLiteTestSetup.Cleanup();
}
```

### Exception

```
Die Testmethode "....SQLiteTest.DoSomeFooTest" hat eine Ausnahme ausgelöst: 
System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException: SQL logic error
no such table: FooTable
    bei System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Prepare(SQLiteConnection cnn, String strSql, SQLiteStatement previous, UInt32 timeoutMS, String& strRemain)
   bei System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.BuildNextCommand()
   bei System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.GetStatement(Int32 index)
   bei System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader.NextResult()
   bei System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader..ctor(SQLiteCommand cmd, CommandBehavior behave)
   bei System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   bei System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(CommandBehavior behavior)
   bei System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   bei ....FooDatabase.DoFoo() in ...\SqliteDatabaseBase.cs:Zeile 83.
   bei ....SQLiteTestBase.DoSomeFooTest() in ...\SQLiteTest.cs:Zeile 30.
```

Comment: Your example shows a wrapped connection, not a wrapped `DBCommand` object. So it should be possible to use one `DbConnection` with many `DbCommand` objects.

Comment: Sorry my mistake! I have updated the code sample how I use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Working Solution approach

I have added a `ConnectionContext` class, where I can set a flag to decide if I want to dispose my `DbConnection` or not.

### Database class

```
public class ConnectionContext : IDisposable
{
    private readonly bool _ContextOwnsConnection;
    public readonly DbConnection Connection;

    public ConnectionContext(DbConnection connection, bool contextOwnsConnection)
    {
        Connection = connection;
        _ContextOwnsConnection = contextOwnsConnection;            
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if(_ContextOwnsConnection)
            Connection.Dispose();
    }
}

public abstract class SqliteBase
{
    public Func<ConnectionContext> GetContext;

    private ConnectionContext _GetConnectionContext()
    {
        return new ConnectionContext(GetConnection(), true);
    }
    private string _ConnectionString;
    private readonly string _Dbfile;

    protected SqliteBase()
    {
        GetContext = _GetConnectionContext;
        _Dbfile = ":memory:";

        _InitConnectionString();
    }

    private void _InitConnectionString()
    {
        SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder
        {
            DataSource = _Dbfile,
            ForeignKeys = true,
            DefaultTimeout = 3,
            DateTimeKind = DateTimeKind.Utc,
            Pooling = true
        };

        _ConnectionString = builder.ConnectionString;
    }

    public DbConnection GetConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            DbConnection dbConnection = SQLiteFactory.Instance.CreateConnection();                
            dbConnection.ConnectionString = _ConnectionString;
            dbConnection.Open();

            return dbConnection;
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error opening database connection.", ex);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a table in the SQL database if it does not exist
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="tableName">The name of the table</param>
    /// <param name="columns">Comma separated column names</param>
    protected void CreateTable(string tableName, string columns)
    {
        using (ConnectionContext context = GetContext())
        {
            using (DbCommand dbCommand = context.Connection.CreateCommand($"create table if not exists {tableName} ({columns})"))
            {
                dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }   
        }                   
    }
}

public class FooDatabase : SqliteBase
{
    public FooDatabase()
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        CreateTable("FooTable", "Foo TEXT");
    }

    public void DoFoo()
    {
        using (ConnectionContext context = GetContext())
        {
            using (DbCommand dbCommand = context.Connection.CreateCommand("Select * from FooTable"))
            {
                dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }   
        }                        
    }
}
```

### Unit Test

```
public abstract class SQLiteTestBase
{
    public static ConnectionContext Connection { get; set; }
    public static FooDatabase Database { get; set; }

    [TestMethod]
    public void DoSomeFooTest()
    {
        Database.DoFoo();
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class SQLiteTest : SQLiteTestBase
{
    [ClassInitialize]
    public static void ClassInit(TestContext context)
    {                 
        Database = new FooDatabase();            
        Database.GetContext = () => Connection;
        Connection = new ConnectionContext(Database.GetConnection(), false);            
    }

    [TestInitialize]
    public void TestInit()
    {
        Connection = new ConnectionContext(Database.GetConnection(), false);
        Database.Initialize();
    }

    [TestCleanup]
    public void TestCleanup()
    {
        Connection.Dispose();
        Connection = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you stopped reading to early. The second paragraph of the link you posted, "In-memory Databases And Shared Cache" describes what you can do and need to do in your case:

The database is deleted after closing *the last* connection if you use the method described in the link you posted.

You need a file URI and `mode=memory` for in-memory *and* `cache=shared` to have multiple connections go to the same named database.

So if your unit tests starts out with a using statement for a connection that is named (for example with the same name as your current test) then inside that using statement, all connections using the same connection string should connect to the same in-memory database.

Comment: Does not solve the problem. This is my `ConnectionString` `data source=:memory:;foreign keys=True;default timeout=3;datetimekind=Utc;pooling=False;mode=memory;cache=shared`.

Comment: So did you implement my suggestion that each unit tests holds an open connection so that *the test* determines what the "last connection" is? If so, please post it.

Comment: Have added a complete (trimmed) example where I get the exception

Comment: @DominicJonas Your connection string does not look like described in the link you posted. You need a file URI, like "file::memory:..."

Comment: If I use `ConnectionString = "file::memory:?cache=shared";` or `ConnectionString = "file:memdb1?mode=memory&cache=shared";` I get the following error *Error opening database connection. ---> System.ArgumentException: Data Source cannot be empty.  Use :memory: to open an in-memory database.*.

Comment: @DominicJonas hm to be honest I remember getting the exact same error message and solving it, but I work at a different company now and don't have access to that source any more... so just heads up: it does work... somehow :)

Answer (score 0):

I was having same issue with sharing in memory sqlite database. My solution was to set connection string to "FullUri=file::memory:?cache=shared"

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a name for the datasource instead of :memory:

```
data source=testName;foreign keys=True;default timeout=3;datetimekind=Utc;pooling=False;mode=memory;cache=shared
```